# C wrapper for C++ class returns incorrect address

Tags: c++, c

My C++ header is

**header.hh**

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>
class A
{
    uint32_t a;
    public: 
        A(){
           a = 0;
        }
        void update(uint32_t b) {
           a = b;
        }
};
#else
typedef struct A A;
#endif //__cplusplus
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
    void* newA(void);
    void deleteA(A* a);
    void update(A*a,uint32_t b);
}
#endif
```

And my c++ file is

**class.cc**

```
#include "header.hh"
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {
    void* newA(void) {
        A* a = new A();
        return (reinterpret_cast <void*> (a));
    }
    void deleteA(A* a) {
         delete a;
    }
    void update(A* a,uint32_t b){
        a->update(b);
    }
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "header.hh"
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    A* a = (A*) newA();
    deleteA(a);
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -ansi -pedantic -std=c99
CCFLAGS=-Wall -g
LDFLAGS=-g -Wall -lstdc++

OBJS=class.o main.o
PROG=test

all:$(PROG)
default: all

%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $<

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS)
    rm -rf $(PROF)
```

When I compile and run this program, I see a segfault when I try to call the destructor in Main.

I went into gdb and found that the address of "a" in class.cc is **0x7fff980097a0** and in main is **0xffffffff980097a0**.

What is causing the addresses to be changed?

I'm using 4.8.4 version of gcc on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: BTW, you may return `A*` instead of `void*` for `newA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compile *main.c* with a C compiler, it won't have the declarations for the `newA`, `deleteA` or `update` functions (they're surrounded with `#ifdef __cplusplus`).

So, it will assume the default signature `int newA()` (similar for the other two).

This means that in this line :

```
A* a = (A*) newA();
```

the value returned by `newA()` is treated as an `int`, then cast to `A*`. The result of casting an `int` to a pointer type is implementation defined. On your platform, it appears that the behavior is what you observed.

Most likely, on your platform, `sizeof(int)` is `4`, while `sizeof(void*)` is `8`. In that case, `0x7fff980097a0` is truncated to `0x980097a0` when treated as an `int`, and then extended to `0xffffffff980097a0` when cast to `A*`. And this is exactly what you observe.

Instead, try this to make the declarations visible to a C compiler :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    void* newA(void);
    void deleteA(A* a);
    void update(A*a,uint32_t b);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: How does 'main.c' even compile?

Comment: @Tchinmai : updated my answer to include a solution.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thank you!. you made my day!

Answer (score 1):

In header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif 

// The header declaration is included both by the the C and the C++ 
// compiler.

void* newA(void);
void deleteA(A* a);
void update(A*a,uint32_t b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} 
#endif
```